# Setting default values for ivars in C++ 2011

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that this is now perfectly acceptable for initializing an ivar to a default value:

```
  class A{
    MyType T=MyValue;
   }
```

The idea is that `MyType` is already defined as a default when the class is instantiated.

But what I need clarification on is whether using the member initializing list of a constructor is still suggested for this ivar. If so, then what would be the point of setting the default value as above?

Comment: Why would you initialize the member variable in a constructor if you're already initializing it this way?

Comment: That is in fact exactly my question @KevinBallard

Comment: What does "ivar" mean?

Comment: @KerrekSB "ivar" == "instance variable" -- common shorthand I've seen everywhere

Comment: @KevinBallard: you may have several constructors with a non-empty subset finding the default useful, or you plan to use a default as some kind of sentinel for run-time detection of accidentally missing initialisation....

Comment: @Fellowshee: "ivar", or "instance variable", is a term typically used with Objective-C.

Comment: @KevinBallard good to know, my background is more in Objective-C, but I assumed the term was not specific to a language community.

Comment: @Fellowshee: ivar is not common C++ parlance... perhaps you've an Objective-C background, or the people you've seen use it do?

Comment: @Fellowshee: It's decidedly not common C++ terminology. If anything, it's a *non-static class member variable*, and classes are completely different things from class instances... Maybe you're coming from a Javascript or PHP background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the value of a member variable by an in-class member initializer permits the specification of a default value for the member, if a sensible default value exists. This avoids repeating the default initialization in constructors where the default is acceptable. The default value can be overridden by a constructor's initializer list if the default is not acceptable.

If there is no acceptable default then it seems pointless using in-class member initializer as each constructor would be initializing it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

- If the class member is always initialized with the same value in all constructors, use the inline initializer. This eliminates redundancy and quite possibly improves readability.
- If different constructors initialize the member differently, use the constructor initializer lists.

It's possible to override the inline initializer in the initializer list, but that's stylistically questionable. If in doubt, don't do it, and/or consult your project's style guide.

Comment: I assume the term `inline initializer` refers to the technique I show in my question?

Comment: @Fellowshee: Yes. The standardese term is "brace-or-equal-initializer", but I thought that wasn't a terribly helpful term :-)